# indefinite system for finding extreme values

Tags: multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, hessian-matrix

The function $f(x,y) = xe^y$ has a false system does this mean that there are no extreme values?

EDIT: false system not an indefinite system sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what an indefinite system means in this context, but since $f(x,y) = g(x)h(y)$ your maximum occurs when both $g,h$ have their respective maxima. For the minimum, note that $g(x)$ and $h(y)$ are both unbounded as $x,y \to \infty$. Also, $h(y)=e^y \ge 0$, so let $(x,y) \to (-\infty,\infty)$.

**UPDATE**

You are right, to find the stationary points you have to solve
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
 = \vec{\nabla} f(x,y)
 = \begin{pmatrix} e^y \\ xe^y \end{pmatrix}
$$
and the first equation has no solutions. Therefore, there are no stationary points of $f(x,y)$. The reason for this can be explained like the original argument above.

Comment: It's the terminology we use in Dutch but I was actually mistaken. We were taught for finding the extrema we have to differentiate the function in respect to each variable, which would give the following system: e^y = 0 && xe^y = 0 and since e^y can never be 0, the system is considered "false", right? So in case the question was to find the extrema, my response would have to be that there are none? Anyways, thank you for your time!

Comment: @LLScheme thanks for the clarification, please see the updated answer.